# ON DUPLICATE UPDATE not works with some row

Tags: php, mysql

I am using ON DUPLICATE UPDATE on my query, some of the result didn't store it. I tried all the possible way, but those still remain the same. here are the database picture.

[image]

Those NULL, is the row which didn't store successfully; the result should be 1 instead of NULL.

```
    if($remark){
$query3 = "INSERT INTO `audit_section_remarkrecord` SET remark = '$remark', form_details_subquestion_id = '$form_details_subquestion_id', form_details_section_id = '$form_details_section_id', audit_section_no = '$audit_no' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
form_details_section_id = '$form_details_section_id' , remark = '$remark'";
$result3 = $db->query($query3); 

$query4 = "UPDATE `remarkrecord_update_details` SET form_details_section_id = '$form_details_section_id', userlog = '$user_staff', ipaddress = '$ip' WHERE form_details_subquestion_id = '$form_details_subquestion_id' AND audit_section_no = '$audit_no' ";
$result4 = $db->query($query4); 
}else{
}

}
```

Table Structure

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some values for the parameters that DO work, and some that DON'T work.  It would be helpful to see a sampling of the values.

Comment: @devlincarnate hi bro, can you let me know any else I can show you? I not understand what values for the parameters you means :)

Comment: post variable value that doesn't work also post table structure

Comment: @rocky updated my question. and also provide table structure. form_details_section_id which is the not insert in some statement.

Comment: @Andrew post values of 

$form_details_subquestion_id ,
$form_details_section_id ,
$audit_no ,
$remark ,
$user_staff

Comment: post structure of remarkrecord_update_details

Answer (score 2):

Try changing one of your columns you are inserting value to primary key or add UNIQUE constraint to the column.

```
ALTER TABLE audit_section_remarkrecord ADD UNIQUE KEY (your column);
```

As there is currently only a unique key on the Primary Key, an auto-increment, you are going to have difficulty generating a unique key clash on an `insert on duplicate key update (IODKU).` Therefore, some other unique key needs to be created (even a composite), that will trigger the clash of a unique key and allow `IODKU` to work as expected.

Comment: ALTER TABLE audit_section_remarkrecord
ADD UNIQUE(form_details_subquestion_id, audit_section_no);

Comment: If you are using ALTER TABLE audit_section_remarkrecord ADD UNIQUE(id); , then your query should be INSERT INTO table_name SET id="$id', ... ON DUPLICATE ..